# " Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page " in Portal Site,

Tags: visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce, customer-portal

I've already googled on this issues and I did all the recommendations, But still Un achieved,

I've created visualforce page to display Attachments on Particular Object for Current Logged in User in Portals,

It is working fine by passsing HardCoded Id over URL (Poratal user) and also By Opening that Page Seperately(apex/MyInvoiceDocs?Id='abd145455562') Its working.

[image: Outside portal Home page, By Hardcoding the One of Portal User Id]

But when I access this page in Portals(Using "where ID=:UserInfo.getUserId()" in controller Query )

Which actually gets Id of current logged in User(Portal enabled) and Displays Attachments

I'm getting " Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page "

Also, This page and Class is already Accessible to that User's Profile(Apex class and VF page access)

Any one Suggest me...

And I didnt used any Lookup field on VF page and I used,

```
 <apex:column headerValue="View / Download">
            <apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a.At.Id)}" target="_blank"> View </apex:outputLink> 
       </apex:column>
```

for Download / view of attachment

Comment: If you have any lookup field on Visualforce page make sure provide access to lookup object from profile.

Comment: @Prabhat Hi Prabhat, I've used a wraper class list to display the Attachment name and Object Name to which Attachment belogs and other field.

Comment: @Prabhat I've updated my quation have a look on It, and I think using global variable like $Action on VF pages that are used for Portal Usrs is Not Prefered.. please suggest me other i will share my class and controller if u need to identify bugs

Comment: @SFDC_Igle you can try one thing. In standard exception Page you will find one line <apex:param value="{!error.messages}" /> change this to <apex:param value="{!error.description}" />. it will surely help you. try this and reload your page.

Comment: @SFDC_lgle How you are loading visualforce page if its through Javascript button then URL could be issue.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma, Hi Sharma,

Thanks for ur Kind reply,

Its now showing, 
Error :  " SVMXC__Service_Order__c does not exist "

It seems like, It is related to " Service Maxx" Managed Package.

Thanks alot

And now how to set this as Best answer here:)

Comment: @ Prabhat Thank you Prabhat, I'm accessing that page using a Command link without JavaScript,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SFDC_Igle you can try one thing. In standard exception Page you will find one line as shown below

```
<apex:param value="{!error.messages}" />
```

which you should change to

```
<apex:param value="{!error.description}" />.
```

Try this and reload your page.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know this trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the object accessible to the user?. Verify also that the required fields such as name are available to the user's profile.

Permissions on the object, fields, classes or VF pages are the most common causes for this type of errors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, And i have given access at Profile for all fields and Objects , which are used in my class and For the Attachments object I didnt see any Object and Field settings in Profiles.

Still I am Getting the Same Issue, Tell me any other work around Please..